# newbie: how to install (which) C++ compiler for w7?

Tags: c++, installation

I've just started programming in C++ (as forced by the teaching staff of the university I am enrolled in) and I can't wrap my head around c++ compilers... I am using Atom as my text editor and I thought a compiler would be a simple {download - install - execute} type of deal, but this whole LLVM thing is confusing to me (on the website, I encountered lots of source files and a host of really weird terms like TOOLCHAIN, target-independent optimizer, intermediate representation, etc.) and I would appreciate any help (I am using Windows7 64bit btw).

thanks a bunch xx

Comment: LLVM is a framework for *creating* compilers, it's not a compiler in itself. You either need to find a Windows build of Clang, GCC or the Microsoft MSVC compiler (which comes with the Visual Studio IDE). There are environments that are simple to install and use for Windows (besides Visual Studio) for example MinGW which uses the GCC compiler.

Comment: yess, now it makes sense, MinGW here I come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows then Install " MingW" compiler. 
Instead I would recommend you to go with "Code Blocks" IDE and install it along with MingW compiler. It's the lightest IDE and best for beginners.

Here is the link to download the code blocks
http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26

If you are not a beginner go with GCC compiler and better install linux and use if you want to become a good developer

Comment: thanks, I've refrained from downloading CodeBlocks because of the degree to which it is associated with highschool students - being a university student, I've got to keep the standardz highhh

Comment: Ok i didn't know you are university student, I thought you are a beginner... Ok then you go on with GCC compiler and install Linux that's the best for developer

Comment: you're absolutely right, that's what I've been told as well, I'll be getting a new laptop soon and I'm def installing Linux as soon as I get it - windows has gone downhill anyway lmaoo